# Matrix subtraction of different size. Elementwise subtraction?

Tags: vectors

**Problem Description:**

I have to solve the following problem.

$
\phi\beta - x
$

$
 \phi_t = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(t) 
  & 
  \sin(t)
 \end{bmatrix}
$

$
 \phi = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \phi_{t=0} 
  & 
  \phi_1 
  & 
  \dots{}
  & 
  \phi_{N-1}
 \end{bmatrix}^T
$
$ 
 =  
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(0) & \sin(0) \\
  \cos(1) & \sin(1) \\
  \cos(2) & \sin(2) \\
  \vdots{} & \vdots{} \\
  \cos(N-1) & \sin(N-1)
 \end{bmatrix}
$

$
 \beta = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \beta_{0}\\
  \beta_{1}
 \end{bmatrix}
$

$
 x= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  x_{0} 
  & 
  x_1
  & 
  \dots{}
  & 
  x_{N-1}
 \end{bmatrix}^T
$

**The real issue:**

So far, everything is good. The part I'm not understanding is that x is a vector in itself. Size between $\phi\beta$ and $x$ don't match for subtraction.

$
x_t =
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{t, 0} &
\dots{}&
w_{t, N-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$

**Suggested Solution:**

In this case, should I treat the subtraction as an elementwise scalar operation? For example, would I be doing something like this?

$
= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(0)\beta_0+\sin(0)\beta_1 - w_{0,0} & \dots & \cos(0)\beta_0+\sin(0)\beta_1-w_{0, N} \\
                                      & \ddots{}& \\
  \cos(N-1)\beta_0+\sin(N-1)\beta_1 - w_{N-1, 0} & \dots{} & \cos(N-1) \beta_0+\sin(N-1)\beta_1 - w_{N-1, N-1} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Because $\phi$ is $n \times 2$ and $\beta$ is $2 \times 1$, the product $\phi\beta$ is an $n \times 1$ column, the same size as $x$...?

Comment: I agree with Andrew, maybe you forgot about the transpose on $x$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang size of $x$ is n x 1 but each element of $x$ is another vector with $w$ that eventually makes it an n x n matrix eventually. I was wondering how to do that part. Or am I missing something here?